# connecting a pyqtSignal from Qrunnable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to make an app that monitors hardware, I would like to use Qthreadpool instead of having a thread for each widget and I am having trouble connecting signals to display the output. I am also getting no errors.

My old code runs fine and displays what it should using QThread:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGuiimport ui
import time
import mem_stats


class MainClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui.Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.mem_worker = MemWorker()
        self.mem_worker.start()
        self.connect(self.mem_worker, QtCore.SIGNAL('MEM_STATS'),self.show_mem_stats)

    def show_mem_stats(self, free_mem):
        self.free_memory_lcd.display(free_mem)


class MemWorker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
    super(MemWorker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            free_mem = mem_stats.free_mem()
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('MEM_STATS'), free_mem)
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MainClass()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

But when i change MemWorker class to QRunnable the code runs with no errors but the QlcdNumber doesn't display anyting.

Here's my new code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import ui
import time
import mem_stats


class WorkerSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    mem_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)


class MainClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.mem_worker = MemWorker()
        self.thread_pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        self.thread_pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)
        self.connect(self.mem_worker.signal, QtCore.SIGNAL('MEM_STATS'), self.show_mem_stats)

    def show_mem_stats(self, free_mem):
        self.free_memory_lcd.display(free_mem)
        self.thread_pool.start(self.mem_worker)


class MemWorker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MemWorker, self).__init__()
        self.signal = WorkerSignals()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            free_mem = mem_stats.free_mem()
            self.signal.mem_signal.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('MEM_STATS'), free_mem)
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MainClass()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not starting the `QRunnable`, you want to start it in the slot and it will never be called if the `QRunnable` is not started. On the other hand, it is currently recommended to use [the new connection syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), and finally it is recommended to use the [`@pyqtSlot decorator`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) that makes the connection from the C++ side, making it faster with fewer resources.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import ui
import time
import mem_stats

class WorkerSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    mem_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)


class MainClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.mem_worker = MemWorker()
        self.thread_pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        self.thread_pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)
        self.mem_worker.signal.mem_signal.connect(self.show_mem_stats)
        self.thread_pool.start(self.mem_worker)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def show_mem_stats(self, free_mem):
        self.free_memory_lcd.display(free_mem)


class MemWorker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MemWorker, self).__init__()
        self.signal = WorkerSignals()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            ree_mem = mem_stats.free_mem()
            self.signal.mem_signal.emit(free_mem)
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MainClass()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: Although the code runs now i get an issue here in the terminal when the script is run. "Qt Concurrent has caught an exception thrown from a worker thread.
This is not supported, exceptions thrown in worker threads must be
caught before control returns to Qt Concurrent."